# Raw Mako template included in another in Pylons

Tags: pylons, mako

I'm trying to include a raw Mako template to make it appear in a textarea with Pylons.

In Pylons, I know I can include one Mako template in another like this:

```
<html>
<body>
Here is some HTML. Now, I want to include a template.
<%include file="${c.a_mako_template}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that I can do the same thing, but have the template appear as raw markup rather than passing through Mako renderer? I'm imagining something like:

```
<%include file="${c.a_mako_template}" render="false" />
```

If that sort of thing is impossible, is the best route to write a Pylons controller that does the inclusion at a later stage?

Could I somehow wrap the file to be included in <%text> tags on the fly, perhaps using <% def>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out a sort of workable solution. It still has one rough bit, but it works.

```
<%
    path = '/path/to/file/'
    f = open(path + c.sourcefile, 'r')
    text_to_edit = f.read()
    f.close()
%>
        <textarea id="code">
        ${text_to_edit}
        </textarea>
```

The first part is just a chunk of Python embedded in the template. It opens the file and extracts the text, thereby bypassing Mako.

The rough bit is the hardcoded path. I'll have to pass that as c.path, or something like that.